# how to set environment variables={EDITOR, VISUAL} to prefer running emacs?

Tags: linux, process, bash, system-environment

## my usecase

I'm currently running GNU Emacs version=24.3.1 graphically (i.e., under GNOME/X though started from a script invoked from a `gnome-terminal` running bash) on a Debian Linux. Just now I was using commandline [`abcde`](http://abcde.einval.com/) to rip audio CDs when its terminal suddenly opened an instance of [The Editor Which Must Not Be Named](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) (to resolve an MP3 tagging question). I realized that, when I setup the box I'm currently using, I failed to set either of the bash environment variables `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` in my `.bashrc`.

## what I want

I nearly always have an graphical/X instance of Emacs running. If I'm **not** running Emacs, I probably have a good reason not to (e.g., a problem with my config files, or that I'm running in a tty). So I'm wondering, how to set `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` so that an application that wants to open an editor does one of the following, in descending order of preference:

1. If I already have an instance of Emacs running (i.e., `pgrep -l emacs | wc -l` -> `1`): open the thing to be edited in a new buffer in the running Emacs.
2. If I do not have an instance of Emacs running (i.e., `pgrep -l emacs | wc -l` -> `0`): start a new instance of `emacs -nw -q` in the terminal.

If I can't get both those preferences, or if there's a reason why I should deprecate one or both, feel free to recommend Something Completely Different.

## solution

`emacsclient` is finicky about its arguments (**TODO:** put a bug on it!), but that can be worked-around:

1. Per [Francesco's suggestion](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/8089/5444) I made `~/bin/emacs-nw-q.sh` (and of course set mode=executable)

   ```
   ### Purely for use with `emacsclient`: see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/8089/5444
   emacs -nw -q $@
   ```
2. Added a stanza to the end of my `.bashrc`:

   ```
   if [[ -z "${EDITOR}" ]] ; then
     export ALTERNATE_EDITOR="${HOME}/bin/emacs-nw-q.sh"
     export EDITOR='emacsclient'
   fi
   if [[ -n "${EDITOR}" && -z "${VISUAL}" ]] ; then
     export VISUAL="${EDITOR}"
   fi
   ```

With this, and

- a running "emacs+server" (i.e., a previously-running graphical Emacs, in which I have done `M-x server-start`): an edit-seeking application successfully opens a buffer in the running emacs on the desired file, and killing that buffer unpauses the edit-seeking application.
- no running emacs+server: an edit-seeking application opens a "bare-bones" Emacs in its same terminal, as desired, with a buffer open to the desired file, and killing that buffer returns control to the edit-seeking application.

## how I failed

I'm putting a stanza at the end of my `.bashrc`: each of the stanzas I've tried is listed below, with the resulting error. To test each stanza, after I [edit, save] `.bashrc` (via `emacs -nw -q ~/.bashrc` in a separate `gnome-terminal` tab), I open a fresh `gnome-terminal` tab to exercise it.

1. With a running emacs (and after `M-x server-start`), following fails with `emacsclient: unrecognized option '-''`

   ```
   if [[ -z "${EDITOR}" ]] ; then
     export EDITOR="emacsclient --alternate-editor='emacs -nw -q'"
   fi
   if [[ -n "${EDITOR}" && -z "${VISUAL}" ]] ; then
     export VISUAL="${EDITOR}"
   fi
   ```
2. With a running emacs+server, following fails with `emacsclient: unrecognized option '-"'`

   ```
   if [[ -z "${EDITOR}" ]] ; then
     export EDITOR='emacsclient --alternate-editor="emacs -nw -q"'
   fi
   if [[ -n "${EDITOR}" && -z "${VISUAL}" ]] ; then
     export VISUAL="${EDITOR}"
   fi
   ```
3. With no running emacs, following fails with `emacsclient: error executing alternate editor ""emacs""`. So I guess `--alternate-editor` just won't take a quoted argument?

   ```
   if [[ -z "${EDITOR}" ]] ; then
     export EDITOR='emacsclient --alternate-editor="emacs"'
   fi
   if [[ -n "${EDITOR}" && -z "${VISUAL}" ]] ; then
     export VISUAL="${EDITOR}"
   fi
   ```
4. With no running emacs, following starts a brand-new graphical emacs with everything (including full `desktop`, which I don't want for this usecase) ... but it gets worse: after I save and kill the buffer opened by the caller app, that caller app just sits there!

   ```
   if [[ -z "${EDITOR}" ]] ; then
     export EDITOR='emacsclient --alternate-editor=emacs'
   fi
   if [[ -n "${EDITOR}" && -z "${VISUAL}" ]] ; then
     export VISUAL="${EDITOR}"
   fi
   ```
5. With no running emacs, following fails with `emacsclient: error executing alternate editor """"`

   ```
   if [[ -z "${EDITOR}" ]] ; then
     export EDITOR='emacsclient --alternate-editor=""' # sorta suggested by erikstokes at above link
   fi
   if [[ -n "${EDITOR}" && -z "${VISUAL}" ]] ; then
     export VISUAL="${EDITOR}"
   fi
   ```
6. With no running emacs, following fails with `emacsclient: error executing alternate editor """"` (i.e., same as previous)

   ```
   if [[ -z "${EDITOR}" ]] ; then
     export EDITOR='emacsclient -a""'
   fi
   if [[ -n "${EDITOR}" && -z "${VISUAL}" ]] ; then
     export VISUAL="${EDITOR}"
   fi
   ```
7. With no running emacs, following fails with `emacsclient: error executing alternate editor "''"`

   ```
   if [[ -z "${EDITOR}" ]] ; then
     export EDITOR="emacsclient -a''"
   fi
   if [[ -n "${EDITOR}" && -z "${VISUAL}" ]] ; then
     export VISUAL="${EDITOR}"
   fi
   ```
8. With no running emacs, following

   ```
   if [[ -z "${EDITOR}" ]] ; then
     export EDITOR='emacsclient'
   fi
   if [[ -n "${EDITOR}" && -z "${VISUAL}" ]] ; then
     export VISUAL="${EDITOR}"
   fi
   ```

   fails with

   ```
   emacsclient: No socket or alternate editor.  Please use:
   --socket-name
   --server-file      (or environment variable EMACS_SERVER_FILE)
   --alternate-editor (or environment variable ALTERNATE_EDITOR)
   ```
9. With no running emacs, following fails with `emacsclient: error executing alternate editor "emacs -nw -q"`

   ```
   if [[ -z "${EDITOR}" ]] ; then
     export ALTERNATE_EDITOR='emacs -nw -q'
     export EDITOR='emacsclient'
   fi
   if [[ -n "${EDITOR}" && -z "${VISUAL}" ]] ; then
     export VISUAL="${EDITOR}"
   fi
   ```
10. Per [Francesco's suggestion](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/8089/5444) I made `~/bin/emacs-nw-q.sh`

    ```
    ### Purely for use with `emacsclient`: see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/8089/5444
    emacs -nw -q
    ```

    and changed my `.bashrc` stanza to

    ```
    if [[ -z "${EDITOR}" ]] ; then
      export ALTERNATE_EDITOR="${HOME}/bin/emacs-nw-q.sh"
      export EDITOR='emacsclient'
    fi
    if [[ -n "${EDITOR}" && -z "${VISUAL}" ]] ; then
      export VISUAL="${EDITOR}"
    fi
    ```

    Good news: with running emacs (and after `M-x server-start`), an edit-seeking application successfully opens a buffer in the running emacs on the desired file, and killing that buffer returns control to the edit-seeking application.

    More good news: with no running emacs+server, the edit-seeking application opens a "bare-bones" Emacs in its same terminal, as desired.

    Bad news: with no running emacs+server, the "bare-bones" Emacs does **not** open the needed file in a buffer. It *does* create the following buffers: `*GNU Emacs*`, `*Messages*`, `*scratch*` ... but not the needed buffer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although it is not clearly documented in its man page, `emacsclient` doesn't seem to accept a full command (i.e. program + arguments) as the alternate editor, only a program.

You could write a small shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec emacs -q -nw "$@"
```

and use it as the alternate editor:

```
export EDITOR='emacsclient -a PATH_TO_YOUR_SCRIPT'
```

Comment: This is very close to what I want! See item#=10 above. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add a "$@" in the script to forward command line arguments to `emacs`. See my edit; it should work as expected now.

Comment: This is the right solution (works well on Linux and macOS, with both `git` and `sudo -e`), but on MSYS2 (Windows): `emacsclient` seems to open the alternate editor and quit immediately, instead of waiting for the process to exit. So applications that refer to `$EDITOR` (like Git) return immediately complaining about an empty file. Tried on Emacs version 26.1.

Answer (score 3):

`emacsclient` has a `-a` option which lets you specify an alternate editor to use if there is not an emacs process with a running server.

So `emacsclient -a emacs` may do what you want.

The alternate editor can also be specified to emacsclient via the `ALTERNATE_EDITOR` environment variable.

As for which of `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` to set: `EDITOR` was traditionally used for line oriented editors such as `ed` or `ex` while `VISUAL` was for screen oriented editors such as `emacs` or `vi`. Thus you probably do not have to set `EDITOR`. I would however suggest setting both as a "belt-and-suspenders" measure as which variable is used is up to the program that is launching your editor, check with its documentation to find out which it would use.

Comment: so set that in both `EDITOR` and `VISUAL`?

Comment: I would suggest doing so. VISUAL is intended to be used for "full screen" applications such as emacs and vi while EDITOR was intended for editors such as ed or ex. Thus some suggest that leaving EDITOR unset is fine. However it is at the discretion of the program that wants to launch your editor what environment variables it may or may not check for your preferences. By setting both you are covered on most of the cases.

Comment: You can also use `emacsclient -a""` to start a new daemon (if one doesn't already exist) and connect to that.

Comment: @erikstokes: would a new daemon start in the current terminal (i.e., `emacs -nw`) or graphically?

Comment: The daemon runs in the background as a child of the current terminal.  Once the daemon is started you can open a file in an existing frame (`emacsclient file`), make a new graphical frame (`emacsclient -c file`) or a new frame in the terminal (`emacsclient -nw file`).  If no frame exists and you don't give any other options you get a graphical frame if possible and a terminal otherwise.

Comment: @erikstokes: `emacsclient -a""` fails in attempt#=6 above (and the very similar quoting attempt#=7). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `emacsclient -a ""` (with a space after `-a`). `emacsclient` is fussy about its arguments.